# How can I run function automatically when calling object at each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, web

How can I run function automatically  when calling object at each time ?

I have the following object :

```
var myObject = {

    main: function(e) {
        //main
    },
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    another: function(e) {
        //another 
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the below functionality?

Calling

```
myObject();
```

would call the `main` method.

But calling

```
myObject().another();
```

Would call the `another` method.

use only **myObecjt()** not **myObecjt.main()**

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by "use as main function".

Comment: The wording of this question is very difficult to understand. You might find you get more help if you explain what you are trying to do a little more.

Comment: The score fluctuations are real.

Comment: i want run the function automatically when i call the object every time

Comment: `myObject` needs to itself be defined as a `Function` to be used as one. A plain `Object` can't be invoked or modified to allow it. However, the reverse is supported of using a `Function` as an `Object`.

Comment: I rephrased your question trying to make it easier to understand, please roll back the edit if I didn't catch your original intention.

Comment: What do you mean by "call the object"?

Comment: How can I run function automatically when calling object at each time ? use only **myObecjt()** not *myObecjt.main()*

Comment: @Rmm I don't mean to offend, but it looks like you may have used a translator to phrase this question. "Is it possible to achieve the below functionality?" doesn't really make sense. And you are not explaining what functionality you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* I understood the question correctly, the code structure you're looking for is as follows:

```
var myObject = (function () {
  var t = {};
  t.main = function() {
    console.log("main");
  };
  t.another = function () {
    console.log("another");
  };
  t.main();
  return t;
});
```

This will result in the following functionality:
Calling `myObject();` will call the `main` method.
Calling `myObject().another();` will call both the `main` and `another` methods.

Comment: Note that this will either leak `main` and `another` as globals (http://jsfiddle.net/jwz7L98t/) or error in strict mode (http://jsfiddle.net/e6Lv3c2h/) as `this` will either refer to the global object or be `undefined`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking for jquery like chaining try something like this

```
function myObject(){
    if(this == window){
        return new myObject();
    }
    //whatever the main method does
    return this;
}
myObject.prototype.x = 1;
myObject.prototype.y = 2;
myObject.prototype.another = function(){
    //whatever the another method does
    return this;
}
```

something like this, would recommend to investigate method chaining and prototypal inheritance, for a clean aplication of this.

or for something more simple

```
function myObject(){
    //whatever the main method does
    return myObject;
}
myObject.x = 1;
myObject.y = 2;
myObject.another = function(){
    //whatever the another method does
    return myObject;//method chaining may continue
}
```